# How to know the status of window service in vb6

Tags: vb6, windows-services

With my code I am able to start and stop the service, basically in my application I am refreshing WIA window service. So before stopping the service I want to know the status .. as of my knowledge `QueryServiceStatus` does this but in my code it is returning 0 (failure).

```vb
' start/stop/pause/continue a service
' SERVICENAME is the
' COMMAND can be   0=Start, 1=Stop, 2=Pause, 3=Continue
'
' returns True if successful, False otherwise
' if any error, call Err.LastDLLError for more information

Function ServiceCommand(ByVal ServiceName As String, ByVal command As Long) As _
    Boolean
    Dim hSCM As Long
    Dim hService As Long
    Dim res As Long

    Dim query As Long
    Dim lpServiceStatus As SERVICE_STATUS

    ' first, check the command
    If command < 0 Or command > 3 Then Err.Raise 5

    ' open the connection to Service Control Manager, exit if error
    hSCM = OpenSCManager(vbNullString, vbNullString, GENERIC_EXECUTE)
    If hSCM = 0 Then Exit Function



    ' open the given service, exit if error
    hService = OpenService(hSCM, ServiceName, GENERIC_EXECUTE)
    If hService = 0 Then GoTo CleanUp

    'fetch the status
    query = QueryServiceStatus(hService, lpServiceStatus)

    ' start the service
    Select Case command
        Case 0
            ' to start a service you must use StartService
            res = StartService(hService, 0, 0)
        Case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE, _
            SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE
            ' these commands use ControlService API
            ' (pass a NULL pointer because no result is expected)
            res = ControlService(hService, command, lpServiceStatus)
    End Select
    If res = 0 Then GoTo CleanUp

    ' return success
    ServiceCommand = True

    CleanUp:
        If hService Then CloseServiceHandle hService
        ' close the SCM
        CloseServiceHandle hSCM

End Function
```

Also if anyone can also tell me few doubts about the window service :

1. Can the same system have 2 different version of window service (WIA 1.0 and WIA 2.0) ?
2. Does the above services have different service name (WIA2.0 name =StiSvc) or same?

Comment: You do not show necessary declares and type definitions -- there's no way to tell if your code works.

Comment: The windows service manager will throw an exception if you try to install a service that has the same name as an existing service.  So, you have to have a different service name to have multiple versions of the service run simultaneously.

Comment: thanks bobRodes... do you have any idea if the WIA 1.0 had the same name(StiSvc) as the WIA 2.0 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is from a sample on freevbcode.com.

```
' Service State - for CurrentState
Public Const SERVICE_STOPPED = &H1
Public Const SERVICE_START_PENDING = &H2
Public Const SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = &H3
Public Const SERVICE_RUNNING = &H4
Public Const SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = &H5
Public Const SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = &H6
Public Const SERVICE_PAUSED = &H7

Type SERVICE_STATUS
    dwServiceType As Long
    dwCurrentState As Long
    dwControlsAccepted As Long
    dwWin32ExitCode As Long
    dwServiceSpecificExitCode As Long
    dwCheckPoint As Long
    dwWaitHint As Long
End Type

Declare Function CloseServiceHandle Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hSCObject As Long) As Long
Declare Function ControlService Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hService As Long, ByVal  dwControl As Long, lpServiceStatus As SERVICE_STATUS) As Long
Declare Function OpenSCManager Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "OpenSCManagerA" (ByVal lpMachineName As String, ByVal lpDatabaseName As String, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long) As Long
Declare Function OpenService Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "OpenServiceA" (ByVal hSCManager As Long, ByVal lpServiceName As String, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long) As Long
Declare Function QueryServiceStatus Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hService As Long, lpServiceStatus As SERVICE_STATUS) As Long
Declare Function StartService Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "StartServiceA" (ByVal hService As Long, ByVal dwNumServiceArgs As Long, ByVal lpServiceArgVectors As Long) As Long


Public Function ServiceStatus(ComputerName As String, ServiceName As String) As String
    Dim ServiceStat As SERVICE_STATUS
    Dim hSManager As Long
    Dim hService As Long
    Dim hServiceStatus As Long

    ServiceStatus = ""
    hSManager = OpenSCManager(ComputerName, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)
    If hSManager <> 0 Then
        hService = OpenService(hSManager, ServiceName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS)
        If hService <> 0 Then
            hServiceStatus = QueryServiceStatus(hService, ServiceStat)
            If hServiceStatus <> 0 Then
                Select Case ServiceStat.dwCurrentState
                Case SERVICE_STOPPED
                    ServiceStatus = "Stopped"
                Case SERVICE_START_PENDING
                    ServiceStatus = "Start Pending"
                Case SERVICE_STOP_PENDING
                    ServiceStatus = "Stop Pending"
                Case SERVICE_RUNNING
                    ServiceStatus = "Running"
                Case SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING
                    ServiceStatus = "Coninue Pending"
                Case SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING
                    ServiceStatus = "Pause Pending"
                Case SERVICE_PAUSED
                    ServiceStatus = "Paused"
                End Select
            End If
            CloseServiceHandle hService
        End If
        CloseServiceHandle hSManager
    End If
End Function
```

The complete sample can be found at [http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=6829.](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=6829) I don't know the answers to your other questions.